# How to apply lifecycle patters in AWS elasticsearch to many indexs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to do [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-create-policy) in AWS elasticsearch, whereby I create a template for the pattern `application-logs-*`, and then I want to apply a index policy `log-rotation-policy` for all indexes which match that expression. I have created my policy successfully, but when I try to create a template like so:

```
PUT _template/application-logs
{
  "index_patterns" : [
      "application-logs-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index.lifecycle.name": "log-rotation-policy", 
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "unknown setting [index.policy_id] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
```

The AWS documentation is extremely [vague](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry I thought I would post this answer anyway because as I was writing this I figured out the problem, the correct key o use is: `opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id` so it should be:

```
PUT _template/application-logs
{
  "index_patterns" : [
      "application-logs-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "opendistro.index_state_management.policy_id": "log-rotation-policy", 
    }
}
```

I found the answer [here](https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/can-you-automatically-manage-indices/2034).